# Parse sequence of tokens into hierarchical type in F#

Tags: parsing, f#

I processed some HTML to extract various information from a website (no proper API exists there), and generated a list of tokens using an F# discriminated union. I have simplified my code to the essence:

```
type tokens =
  | A of string
  | B of int
  | C of string

let input = [A "1"; B 2; C "2.1"; C "2.2"; B 3; C "3.1"]

// how to transform the input to the following ???

let desiredOutput = [A "1", [[ B 2, [ C "2.1"; C "2.2" ]]; [B 3, [ C "3.1" ]]]]
```

This roughly corresponds to parsing the grammar: g -> A b* ; b -> B c* ; c-> C

The key thing is my token list is flat, but I want to work with the hierarchy implied by the grammar.

Perhaps there is another representation of my desiredOutput which would be better; what I really want to do is process exactly one A followed by a zero or more sequence of Bs, which happen to contain zero or more Cs.

I've looked at parser combinators articles, e.g. about FParsec, but I couldn't find a good solution that allows me to start from a list of tokens rather than a stream of characters. I'm familiar with imperative techniques for parsing, but I don't know what is idiomatic F#.

**Progress made due to Answer**

Thanks to the answer from Vandroiy, I was able to write the following to move forward a hobby project I am working on to learn idiomatic F# (and also to scrape quiz websites).

```
// transform flat data scraped from a Quiz website into a hierarchical data structure

type ScrapedQuiz =
  | Title of string
  | Description of string
  | Blurb of string * picture: string
  | QuizId of string
  | Question of num:string * text:string * picture : string
  | Answer of text:string
  | Error of exn

let input = 
  [Title "Example Quiz Scraped from a website";
   Description "What the Quiz is about";
   Blurb ("more details","and a URL for a picture");
   Question ("#1", "How good is F#", "URL to picture of new F# logo");
   Answer ("we likes it");
   Answer ("we very likes it");
   Question ("#2", "How useful is Stack Overflow", "URL to picture of Stack Overflow logo");
   Answer ("very good today");
   Answer ("lobsters");
  ]

type Quiz =
  { Title : string
    Description : string
    Blurb : string * PictureURL 
    Questions : Quest list }
and Quest =
  { Number : string
    Text : string
    Pic : PictureURL
    Answers : string list}
and PictureURL = string

let errorMessage = "unexpected input format"

let parseList reader input =
  let rec run acc inp =
    match reader inp with
    | Some(o, inp') -> run (o :: acc) inp'
    | None -> List.rev acc, inp
  run [] input

let readAnswer = function Answer(a) :: t -> Some(a, t) | _ -> None

let readDescription = 
                function Description(a) :: t -> (a, t) | _ -> failwith errorMessage
let readBlurb = function Blurb(a,b) :: t -> ((a,b),t)  | _ -> failwith errorMessage

let readQuests = function
  | Question(n,txt,pic) :: t ->
      let answers, input' = parseList readAnswer t
      Some( { Number=n; Text=txt; Pic=pic; Answers = answers}, input')
  | _ -> None

let readQuiz = function
  | Title(s) :: t ->
      let d,  input'   = readDescription t
      let b,  input''  = readBlurb input'
      let qs, input''' = parseList readQuests input''
      Some( { Title = s; Description = d; Blurb = b; Questions = qs}, input''')
  | _ -> None

match readQuiz input with
  | Some(a, []) -> a
  | _ -> failwith errorMessage
```

I could not have written this yesterday; neither the target data type, nor the parsing code. I see room for improvement, but I think I have started to meet my goal of not writing C# in F#.

Comment: I don't think you really need FParsec for this but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can imagine code that traverses the tokens and uses mutable data structures to build a hierarchy on the fly, but I was looking for something more declarative; hence my hunch about combinators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it might help to first find a good representation.

### Original output format

I presume the suggested output form, in standard printing, would be:

```
[(A "1", [(B 2, [C "2.1"; C "2.2"]); (B 3, [C "3.1"])])]
```

(This differs from the one in the question in the amount of list levels.) The code I used to get there is ugly. In part, this is because it abstracts at an awkward position, constraining input and output types very far without giving them a well-defined type. I'm posting it for the sake of completeness, but I recommend to skip over it.

```
let rec readBranch checkOne readInner acc = function
    | h :: t when checkOne h ->
        let dat, inp' = readInner t
        readBranch checkOne readInner ((h, dat) :: acc) inp'
    | l -> List.rev acc, l

let rec readCs acc = function
    | C(s) :: t -> readCs (C(s) :: acc) t
    | l -> List.rev acc, l

let readBs = readBranch (function B _ -> true | _ -> false) (readCs []) []
let readAs = readBranch (function A _ -> true | _ -> false) readBs []

input |> readAs |> fst
```

Surely, other people can do this more sensibly, but I doubt it would tackle the main problem: we're just projecting one weird data structure to the next. If it is difficult to read or formulate a parser's output format, there is probably something going wrong.

### Strongly typed output

Rather than focus on *how* we are parsing, I prefer to first pay attention to *what we are parsing into*. These A B C things don't mean anything to me. Let's say they represent objects:

```
type Bravo =
    { ID : int
      Charlies : string list }

type Alpha =
    { Name : string
      Bravos : Bravo list }
```

There are two places where sequences of objects of the same type are parsed. Let's create a helper that repeatedly uses a specific parser to read a list of objects:

```
/// Parses objects into a list. reader takes an input and returns either
/// Some(parsed item, new input state), or None if the list is finished.
/// Returns a list of parsed objects and the remaining input.
let parseList reader input =
    let rec run acc inp =
        match reader inp with
        | Some(o, inp') -> run (o :: acc) inp'
        | None -> List.rev acc, inp
    run [] input
```

Note that this is quite generic in the type of `input`. This helper could be used with strings, sequences, or whatever.

Now, we add concrete parsers. The following functions have the signature used in `reader` in the helper; they either return the parsed object and the remaining input, or None if parsing wasn't possible.

```
let readC = function C(s) :: t -> Some(s, t) | _ -> None

let readB = function
    | B(i) :: t ->
        let charlies, input' = parseList readC t
        Some( { ID = i; Charlies = charlies }, input' )
    | _ -> None

let readA = function
    | A(s) :: t ->
        let bravos, input' = parseList readB t
        Some( { Name = s; Bravos = bravos }, input' )
    | _ -> None
```

The code for reading Alphas and Bravos is practically a duplicate. If that happens in production code, I would recommend again to check *whether the data structure is optimal*, and only look at improving the algorithm afterwards.

We request to read one A into one Alpha, which was the goal after all:

```
match readA input with
| Some(a, []) -> a
| _ -> failwith "Unexpected input format"
```

There may be many better ways to do the parsing, especially when knowing more about the exact problem. The important fact is not how the parser works, but what the output looks like, which will be the focus when actual work is done in the program. The second version's output should be much easier to navigate in both code and debugger:

```
val it : Alpha =
    { Name = "1";
      Bravos = [ { ID = 2; Charlies = ["2.1"; "2.2"] }
                 { ID = 3; Charlies = ["3.1"] } ] }
```

One could take this a step further and replace the tokenized data structure with DOM (Document Object Model). Then, the first step would be to read HTML into DOM using a standard parsing library. In a second step, the concrete parsers would construct objects, using the DOM representation as input, calling one another top-down.

Comment: This is very helpful. I am not at all attached to the data structure I offered as a target - it was my first effort to express the hierarchy implied by my little grammar for the input token list; you nailed that aspect in your answer. I didn't think the input was that weird; just a flat list of tokens with values that a tool like lex might produce? Your parsing code for your proposed target type is easy to follow, and does what I wanted.

Comment: I guess the tokens aren't _that_ weird if you are parsing HTML without a library -- which sounds bothersome, but I guess that's a different topic. Anyway, if you end up with a high-level data structure in the end, it's all good! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

To work with structured hierarchy, you have to create matching structure of types. Something like

```
type 
   RootType = Level1 list
and
   Level1 = 
     | A of string
     | B of Level2 list
     | C of string
and 
   Level2 = 
     { b: int; c: string list }
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice to seek a specific type for `desiredOutput`. Your types don't quite match my grammar (e.g. there are no Cs in Level1); but I see where you are going. My major stumbling block is writing the transform function that builds a type like yours given the input token list and required grammar. I could do it in a C# imperative style, perhaps I should have, but I am stubborn to learn F# functional idioms for this problem if they exist.